# Is there any tool which detects race conditions at runtime and rewrites code to avoid them in future

Tags: c, linux, race-condition

I have seen tools which can run a multithreaded program deterministically, even in the presence of race conditions. Now I wonder if there is any tool which can actually detect races and rewrite the code (at runtime) to not have the detected races in the future.

Does such kind of a tool exists? Or is it too hard to create one? I think it can be created with a tool that does dynamic binary translation of code, such as PIN or valgrind.

Comment: I don't think this is even *conceptially possible*...

Comment: Detecting race conditions is an unsolvable problem (like the halting problem is on Turing machines).

Comment: The problem is that on modern systems you easily can have "race" conditions even if you don't use threads. Your program can be interrupted in the middle of execution and a signal handler can kick in. So even a strict linearization of your code wouldn't help.

Comment: Well Basile, you could actually detect race conditions for example if you run two replicas. Make them execute deterministically or implement record/replaying of locks, system calls, signals etc. And then if their memory contents diverge, you can say its either due to race condition or some soft error.

Comment: Frameworks to run threaded programs deterministically effectively do rewrite the code to avoid race conditions - I can't see why doing this only after race conditions have occurred would be preferable.  Note that these tools don't ensure that events occur in the intended order (the computer has no way of knowing what that is), just that they will take place in the same order each time you run the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While running a program in a deterministic manner is too much to ask, detecting some (if not all) race conditions is not difficult.

A lot of research is presently happening in this area. And you are on the right track with

PIN -------> Intel Parallel Studio
Valgrind --> Cachegrind and ThreadSanitizer 1.0

There are many open source and commercial tools. I used to work on 1

The way such tools work is that they track lock and other information per memory access and maintain a history of previous accesses. Every access is compared with history of previous accesses. There is more to it.

Answer (score 5):

A [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) means that the outcome of your computation depends on the timing of events occurring (interrupts, scheduler, etc.). What developers typically *mean* (what what I assume you also mean) is that the program is "correct" most of the time and only sometimes fails - a bug triggered by a race condition which only happens rarely.

How is some automated detection algorithm supposed to know what is the desired outcome and what not?
And even if it could do that: Knowing that it happened and figuring out how and then fixing it is usually way more difficult. I'm sure you can reduce this problem to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

At work we have played around with some frameworks which allow to create unit tests to detect race conditions (I can have a look when I'm back at work what it is called), but it's based on enumerating all possible thread schedules. As a simple test we have let it run on a concurrent queue implemention and the test case with 1 consumer and 1 producer and a queue capacity of 1 took a few seconds to run. Simply increasing the queue capacity to 2 made it run for several days. Might be that the tool wasn't too good but it shows the number of possible combinations explodes really fast.

Comment: You could run two replicas of the same program deterministically or by record/replaying of syncronization objects, sytem calls, signals etc. Then if you see a divergence in them, its probably due to race condition. What do you think?

Comment: @user1018562: How do you detect "divergence"?